# English translation Gaston Darboux paper works

Tags: reference-request, translation

I'm looking for an English translation of Gaston Darboux's thesis:

> *Sur les équations aux dérivées partielles du second ordre*
>
> and
>
> *Mémoire sur la théorie des fonctions discontinues*

Does anyone know where can I find it? I wasn't able to google it, so it might be very nice to provide me any suggestions to find it.

Comment: I doubt translations were ever published of these papers ([**19**](//archive.org/details/catalogueofscien07royarich/page/484), [**53**](//archive.org/details/catalogueofscien09royarich/page/634)), which incidentally, were not his [thesis](//genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=34254). You can likely get a passable machine translation of the pdfs on [numdam](http://www.numdam.org/journals/ASENS/).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I have always been in mind that these papers is important part of modern math analysis, so translations should be sth obvious. Are u really sure that there is no any published translations?

Comment: Well, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, but I guess any translations *would* be listed in such histories as [Hawkins](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2002j:01013) or [Pier](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=98k:01003) if published before them.